# getting an error while trying to connect to web service with soap

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I'm having a SOAP related problem in PHP. The complete request including headers should look like the example below.

```
POST /fastjet/vrsxmlservice/VrsXmlWebService3.asmx HTTP/1.1
```

Host: customer3.videcom.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://videcom.com/RunVRSCommand"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <msg xmlns="http://videcom.com/">
      <Token>string</Token>
      <Command>string</Command>
    </msg>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and I call like this:

```
    $client = new soapClient('http://www.customer3.videcom.com//fastjet/vrsxmlservice/VrsXmlWebService3.asmx');


$client->$client->RunVRSCommand(array('token'=>myToken, 'command'=>theCommand));
```

but I get an error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Unable to parse URL

Answer (score 0):

You have two forward slashes in your URL. You should only have one after the `.com`:

```
$client = new soapClient('http://www.customer3.videcom.com/fastjet/vrsxmlservice/VrsXmlWebService3.asmx');
```

Comment: tried that but got error: Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://www.customer3.videcom.com/fastjet/vrsxmlservice/VrsXmlWebService3.asmx' : failed to load external entity "http://www.customer3.videcom.com/fastjet/vrsxmlservice/VrsXmlWebService3.asmx"